# Puppet server and puppet agent 4.8

Tags: puppet

I have a question on the installation process for windows based modules to be controlled via a puppet master.

**Curent setup:**

1. Puppetmaster linux server
2. Windows 7 workstation running puppet agent
   and successfully connect to puppetmaster.

I want to start using a module to control the local security polices on the windows 7 machine. https://forge.puppet.com/cannonps/local_security_policy

I am a little confused as to where I need to install this module.

Do I  need to install on:

- Windows machine only
- Puppetmaster only
- Both agent and puppet master

thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the module on your master, inside the `$modulepath` directory. See here for more information:

https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/dirs_modulepath.html

Once that's done, you need to set up your [main manifest](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/dirs_manifest.html) and then include the module. The info in the docs should be enough to get you going.